# WordPress search in custom table data

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress. Is it possible to search function in a custom table data on front end?

Suppose I have a table `arabic list` and I have 7,000 rows in this table. Is there any plugin that can find the row data in this table and show the result of that row data? Something like this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-searchable-data-entry-system/

This plugin has only one problem: Suppose I save this data in a row:

> اور ان عورتوں کے شر سے جو گرہوں میں پھونکتی ہیں

When user search this word `عورتوں`, on front-end, it shows `no result found`, however, if user search `اور`, then it shows the full line in the result. It seems that this plugin match only first word, whereas, I want to show full row data when any word we write in the search bar.